# Setting Focus on Textbox after manual tab switch

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus, tabcontrol

I would like to have a button that switches a tab control to a specific tab item and afterwards set a focus on a textbox within that tab item.

For this I have an event handler for the click event like this

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
    MyTextBox.Focus();
}
```

This does not work, the tab item is changed but the text box remains without focus. How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call UpdateLayout before focusing the textbox:

```
  MyTabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
  UpdateLayout();
  MyTextBox.Focus();
```

Comment: This does not seem to work reliably in the selection changed event of the tab. Is there a solution to that?